# Convert asp.net C# to vb

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, routes

I am trying to convert this code, but getting some error [this](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2012/06/18/Domain-based-routing-with-ASPNET-Web-API.aspx) is the main link of the code.

I am getting these 2 errors:

> *Type "domainroute is not defined*

and

> *'optional' is not a member of 'system.web.UI.webControls.routeParameter'*

Code:

```
public class HttpDomainRoute
  : DomainRoute
{
  public HttpDomainRoute(string domain, string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults)
      : base(domain, url, defaults, HttpControllerRouteHandler.Instance)
  {
  }

  public HttpDomainRoute(string domain, string url, object defaults)
     : base(domain, url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), HttpControllerRouteHandler.Instance)
 {
 }
}
```

**to this asp.net vb 4**

```
Public Class HttpDomainRoute

     Inherits DomainRoute

    Public Sub New(domain As String, url As String, defaults As RouteValueDictionary)
      MyBase.New(domain, url, defaults, HttpControllerRouteHandler.Instance)
    End Sub


    Public Sub New(domain As String, url As String, defaults As Object)
        MyBase.New(domain, url, New RouteValueDictionary(defaults), HttpControllerRouteHandler.Instance)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class seems to inherit from a class called `DomainRoute`. This is not a standard class that is part of the MVC framework so make sure you also have this class defined. Or at least reference the assembly where it resides. I guess you've taken it [`from here`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12942021/29407). So go ahead and include that class as well.

Comment: I am new in asp.net. can you please give me steps to do so... and it is asp.net 4 webform. and im trying to use routing in global.asax page.

Comment: What kind of guidance do you need more specifically? What difficulties did you encounter when you attempted to convert the `DomainRoute` class to VB.NET once you downloaded the C# version? I am not quite sure how I can help.

Comment: I am trying to implement this [link](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2012/06/18/Domain-based-routing-with-ASPNET-Web-API.aspx) to my project. i do not have full code of it. it is in C# so i used online telerik code converter service and convert it but as i mentioned i am getting error now..

Comment: There's a link on the bottom of the article where you could download the full C# version: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/file.axd?file=2012%2f6%2fWebApiSubdomainRouting.zip Inside you will find everything that is necessary for this to work. Look inside the `WebApiSubdomainRouting\WebApiSubdomainRouting\Code` folder. There you have the `DomainData.cs`, `DomainRoute.cs`, `HttpDomainRoute.cs` and `LinkExtensions.cs` classes. All that's left now for you is to translate them to VB.NET. Don't hesitate to ask for help if you encounter some specific problems with this task.

Comment: I found a free SharpDevelop4.3 software to convert full project C# to vb. after converting full project then i ll give you update...

Answer (score 0):

There is a download link at the bottom. Try to download it and convert the whole code using this [free converter](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Instant_VB.html). If you download you can find it in the code folder the ***`DomainRoute class`***. Try to include that class it in your project

Comment: i do not have the full code. i am implementing this website method of capturing subdomain and route [link](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2012/06/18/Domain-based-routing-with-ASPNET-Web-API.aspx)

Comment: There is a download option in the link you provided with full source code.